# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new enough to ajax calls and JS, i'm getting the the above error. 
I have read other questions with this error and still can't find an answer.
Could some one please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
$scope.getOrgInfo = function(resEmailID) {

    $http
        .get('http://peoplefinder-api.pf.g4ihos.itcs.hpecorp.net/v1.0/person/mgr/' + resEmailID)
        .success(function(result) {

                $scope.orgInfo = result.result;
                var Org_table = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < result.result.length; i++) {
                    Org_table += "<tr><td><img src='" + result.result[i][0].hpPictureThumbnailURI + "' </img></td><td>" + result.result[i][0].cn + "</td><td>" + result.result[i][0].uid + "</td></tr>";
                }
                $("#Chart_Table").append(Org_table);
                alert("working");
            }
    }
```

Comment: you didn't put the closing parenthesis for `.success` function.

Comment: Close the success function. And to fix this error there is no expertise needed in ajax calls. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$scope.getOrgInfo = function(resEmailID) {

    $http.get('http://peoplefinder-api.pf.g4ihos.itcs.hpecorp.net/v1.0/person/mgr/' + resEmailID)
        .success(function(result) {

                $scope.orgInfo = result.result;
                var Org_table = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < result.result.length; i++) {
                    Org_table += "<tr><td><img src='" + result.result[i][0].hpPictureThumbnailURI + "' </img></td><td>" + result.result[i][0].cn + "</td><td>" + result.result[i][0].uid + "</td></tr>";
                }
                $("#Chart_Table").append(Org_table);
                alert("working");
            })
    }
```

Comment: This question should be closed. It doesn't worth an answer.

Comment: So take it out on the people trying to help?

Comment: @adam-beck This cannot be counted as a help. That's why SO is keeping a close reason like that (**a simple typographical error**)

Comment: I agree that the question should be closed but don't assume these answers won't help OP. And they are correct. Downvoting correct answers is dumb.

Comment: @adam-beck Shouldn't "the correct" answer include some useful information about what OP missed? This answer to me is just "i fixed your code and I won't tell how".

Comment: Sure! But then the downvoters could at least explain that in the comments. There were 3 correct answers and several people went through and downvoted all of them without explaining. Maybe the people are trying to help don't know all the rules or guidelines.

Comment: @adam-beck That I agree :)